# Calculating if Romeo and Juliet will stay together always or not.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, applications

I have two equations which describe the Love of Romeo for Juliet (R) and Love of Juliet for Romeo (J) as a function of time, $t$.

$R=-c_1e^{3t}-c_2e^{2t}$

$J=2c_1e^{3t}+c_2e^{2t}$

They will stay together forever if $R(t) \gt 0$ and $J(t) \gt 0$, for all $t  \ge 0$.

How to determine if they will stay forever or not?

Comment: Out of interest, where is this problem from?

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames Saw it on chegg, but I thought the answer was wrong in it. So I solved the system of equations, and go the above result, but I was confused on ways to proof the duration of this love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on the feeling, not the intensity (divide by $^{3}$), and let time pass towards eternity ($\to \infty$); or the end of it.